# gcc: switch or pragma to suppress the "%p" format warning for non-void pointers?

Tags: c++, gcc

Is there a magic incantation to keep gcc from complaining if the argument for the %p format specifier is not a `void*`?

A pragma would be ideal because I could put that in my standard compiler config header and so save the problem once and for all, instead of having to fiddle with project/make files every time...

Normally I prefer the equivalent of -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic with all compilers because warnings on clean source often indicate a mistake on my part, or that the compiler may be losing the plot. However, I can see no possible benefit in cluttering my source code with superfluous casts (C style no less, which I haven't used in years, or the extra-long hyper-cluttering ones), so this particular warning needs to go away.

*Addendum: I know that typedefs and/or templates can reduce the inline clutter to one letter and a pair of parens but they require extra out-of-line clutter. That stuff is noise, it reduces clarity and expressiveness instead of improving them.*

*However, it is my choice not to want this warning, and my goal to make it go away. It is rather silly anyway, since actually occurring problems with pointers (near, far, based, whatever) are orthogonal to the void-ness of the pointer... And to preempt other potential objections, I'm talking about plain data pointers, not function pointers, pointers to members, closures or whatnot. Should I ever need to port something to an oddball platform like Konrad Zuse's Z1 then I can adapt the compiler config header to not suppress that warning on that particular platform...*

Comment: I don't think that the C++ standard guarantees that `sizeof(void *) == sizeof(T *)` for any `T` (thus allowing “fat pointers”) so I'd rather take this warning to heart.  Also, you don't need (nor should) use a C-style cast.  A `static_cast<void *>` should be used.

Comment: Why would you want to suppress a warning telling you that something you have done is _wrong_?

Comment: @5gon12eder: I'll disagree about the C-style cast, if it's an obvious pointer, as being verbose does not equal being clear. But otherwise you are spot-on. Well, actually equal size isn't really enough for same representation, and even that wouldn't cut it anyway...

Comment: @Deduplicator But the point is precisely that a C style cast is pretty nuclear, and it’s *not* at all clear what type we’re dealing with. At the bare minimum, wrap the (`static_`-) cast into a function `as_void`, which only accepts pointer-to-object arguments. I don’t think a C-style cast can compete in clarity with `as_void(my_ptr)`.

Comment: Passing a non-`void*` to `printf()` when using the format specifier `%p` is undefined behavior (according to 7.21.6.1 paragraph 8: "... The argument shall be a pointer to void. ...". You should *act* upon the warning rather than suppress it.

Comment: @5gon12eder `void *` and `char *` are guaranteed the same ... others, not so much

Comment: why are you using `printf` in `c++` anyway ;)

Comment: @MattMcNabb: It's far superior to `cout` and `<<` for formatting. Unless one wants to output custom types, won't ever want to internationalize, ... Naturally, a type-safe alternative based on the printf-form, using variadic templates, and having the advantages of both and the disadvantages of neither is even better.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be such an option. The `-Wformat` family of options to GCC are documented [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/Warning-Options.html) (search for `-Wformat`). If there were a switch for what you want to do, I'd expect it to be found here.